# How to split data based on multiple variables in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I would like to split my data into almost even sized training and test set with the aim to achieve almost equal (as equal as possible) distributions for the variables "age", "sex", and "scanner" in both samples. The groups of the variable "site" should be separated (for example S01, S03, S04, S10, .. in the training set and S02, S05, S06,... in the test set).
My sample data looks as follows:

```
set.seed(2)
data <- data.frame(sex = sample(c("f","m"), 6500, replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.52, 0.48)),
               scanner = sample(c("x", "Y"), 6500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.25, 0.75)),
               site = sample(c("S01", "S02", "S03", "S04", "S05", "S06", "S07", "S08", "S09", "S10", "S11", "S12", "S13", "S14",
                               "S15", "S16", "S17","S18", "S19"), 6500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.04, .07, .05, .04, .07, .04, .03,
                                                                                                 .05, .07, .04, .07, .07, .04, .12,
                                                                                                 .04, .08, .04, .02, .02)),
               age = rnorm(6500, mean = 117.5, sd = 8.5))
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: By equal distributions, do you mean some sort of stratified sampling? Or do you just want a set number of samples per combination of the variables you are splitting?

Comment: Looks like odd/even, so I wonder does `%% == 1` work on strings?

Comment: Stratified systematic sampling might help

Comment: It appears that the overriding condition is that each site is in either the training or the test data set, not both. The other conditions are flexible - that the training and test datasets have roughly equal numbers, and that the "sex", "scanner", and "age" variables have roughly similar distributions within the test and training data sets. Is this a fair summary of what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks for rephrasing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create_groups` function from the **minDiff** package may be what you're looking for.

**Description**

> Is used to assign a set of items to N groups. Differences between
> groups are minimized with regard to specified criteria (E.g.: minimize
> differences in mean test scores between school classes).

For this problem, the `site` variable is fixed - the values must be separated between the train and the test data sets. So, aggregate the other criteria on `site` and then use this aggregated datset in the function whereby the criteria to use for minimizing the differences are the mean and sd ages, and the proportions of males (or females) and scanner type "Y" (or "x").

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("m-Py/minDiff")

library(minDiff)
library(dplyr)

Sites <- data %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            sex_m=sum(sex=="m")/n(),
            scanner_Y=sum(scanner=="Y")/n(),
            age_mu=mean(age),
            age_sd=sd(age)) %>% 
            as.data.frame()   # `create_groups` only accepts pure data frames, tbls aren't allowed.
```

Now create the 2 groups based on this aggregated data frame.

```
Sites <- create_groups(Sites, 
                       criteria_scale=names(Sites)[-1],
                       sets_n=2, 
                       equalize=list(mean, sd), 
                       exact=TRUE,  # gives "optimum" result.
                                    # FALSE is quicker but tries only 100 samples at random
                       talk=TRUE)   # show the progress as it takes a while...
```

The result (after about 2 minutes) is a data frame containing a new variable called `newSet`.

```
head(Sites)
#   site   n     sex_m scanner_Y   age_mu   age_sd newSet
#1   S01 244 0.4959016 0.7377049 118.3024 8.292912      2
#2   S02 466 0.5107296 0.7575107 117.1656 8.491649      2
#3   S03 354 0.4548023 0.7175141 117.6626 8.095703      1
#4   S04 263 0.5247148 0.7870722 118.2087 8.475679      1
#5   S05 438 0.5319635 0.7488584 117.6617 8.826479      1
#6   S06 249 0.5180723 0.7510040 117.0743 8.090794      2
```

We can check the distributions of variables between the two sets:

```
aggregate(cbind(n,sex_m, scanner_Y, age_mu, age_sd)~newSet, FUN=sum, data=Sites)
#  newSet    n    sex_m scanner_Y   age_mu   age_sd
#1      1 3450 4.826725  7.599581 1174.639 84.71687
#2      2 3050 4.267651  6.828945 1057.254 76.60529
```

Not too bad. Now merge this data with the original one.

```
dataSet <- merge(data, subset(Sites, select=c("site","newSet")))
```

We can now check the distributions of variables in the whole data.

```
dataSet %>%
  group_by(newSet) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            sex_m=sum(sex=="m")/n(),
            scanner_Y=sum(scanner=="Y")/n(),
            age_mu=mean(age),
            age_sd=sd(age))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  newSet     n sex_m scanner_Y age_mu age_sd
   <int> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1      1  3450 0.486     0.757   118.   8.42
2      2  3050 0.482     0.759   118.   8.49
```

Seems reasonable. The sample sizes are not too dissimilar, but the proportion of males and "Y" scanner types are very close, as is the distribution of ages.

You can then create your train and test datasets.

```
train <- filter(dataSet, newSet==1)
test <- filter(dataSet, newSet==2)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!!